# Video meta data using YouTube Data API v3

Tags: youtube, youtube-data-api

By using search example, i am able to get video details like name, id, thumb nail URL. But how can i get video total duration using YouTube Data API. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You will have to make a call to the Youtube Data API's Video resource after you make the search call. You can put up to 50 video id's in search, so you wont have to call it for each element.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list

You'll want to set part=contentDetails, because duration is there.

For example the following call:

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=9bZkp7q19f0&part=contentDetails&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
Gives this result:

```
{
 "kind": "youtube#videoListResponse",
 "etag": "\"XlbeM5oNbUofJuiuGi6IkumnZR8/ny1S4th-ku477VARrY_U4tIqcTw\"",
 "items": [
  {

   "id": "9bZkp7q19f0",
   "kind": "youtube#video",
   "etag": "\"XlbeM5oNbUofJuiuGi6IkumnZR8/HN8ILnw-DBXyCcTsc7JG0z51BGg\"",
   "contentDetails": {
    "duration": "PT4M13S",
    "dimension": "2d",
    "definition": "hd",
    "caption": "false",
    "licensedContent": true,
    "regionRestriction": {
     "blocked": [
      "DE"
     ]
    }
   }
  }
 ]
}
```