# Storing YouTube metadata

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, youtube-iframe-api

I've read YouTube's Terms of Service several times and have Googled this question tirelessly with no concrete answer. This is not a legal question about my specific YouTube API client, I just want to know if any YouTube developer has used the API in this way. I'm working on a side project for myself that's essentially an Instagram-YouTube mashup. I am a YouTube developer with an API key. Can my API client store a videos title, description and id in my database when my users like a video on my client? I don't know how else I can keep track of my users liked videos within my client.

Comment: [This page](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started) says that caching is allowed for API resources and their etags, so yes, you can store them, but you should also go look up the video again every so often to ensure it still exists.

Comment: In addition to @Adam 's answer, try using [video:list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) of YouTube Data API. You'll want to set `part=snippets,contentDetails` to get the duration  under `contentDetails` and `title,description` under `snippet` part.

Comment: There is a related SO [post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24301858/5995040) that show how to get the metadata for the video, you can also use the [Try this API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) to familiarize yourself on how to form a request to Youtube Data API. As long as you are not violating Youtube's Term of Service, I think you can store the metadata of the video. Hope this helps.

Comment: @Mr.Rebot I already have everything working. This was not a technical issue. I was looking to see if anyone was familiar enough with the TOS to know if what I'm doing is allowed. The TOS is very difficult to decipher regarding the storage of metadata. I'm looking to contact the YT developer advocate to find out because no one seems to know for sure.

Comment: @TomDeVito, I think that would be the best action to do. Then you can share it here for future readers

Answer (score 0):

Since you already specified that this is in fact not a legal question, the short answer is: Yes, you can (meaning it is possible).

There is one more possibility coming to mind, though:

You could authenticate users via [OAuth 2.0](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication) using the [`https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/auth/server-side-web-apps#identify-access-scopes) scope. That way, you can manage their liked videos and add/remove videos to this list when a user clicks the according buttons on your website (you can also check if any given video is already liked by the user). In this case, all the track-keeping is done by YouTube itself. This ultimately means that whenever a user likes a video in your app, they also like it on the YouTube website. This may or may not be desired, it is for you to decide that.